# Which string is right in this base 64 encoding?

Tags: base64

I'm newbie in base64. I made some tests. I saw some stranges

When I encode "Nguyen Tran Viet A" by Terminal, it produce:

```
vietiPhone:~ vietnt$ echo "Nguyen Tran Viet A" | openssl enc -base64
Tmd1eWVuIFRyYW4gVmlldCBBCg==
```

But then I ran some libs ( in Objective-C), it produce:

```
Tmd1eWVuIFRyYW4gVmlldCBB
```

Which is right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` produces an EOL at end of output, so it gets encoded with OpenSSL. Try the `-n` option:

```
$ echo -n "Nguyen Tran Viet A" | openssl enc -base64
Tmd1eWVuIFRyYW4gVmlldCBB
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because **`echo` command appends a `\n`** after the string in *STDOUT*. To prevent it. Use the following syntax,

```
echo -n "Nguyen Tran Viet A" | openssl enc -base64
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the end of line character.  When you use "echo" it outputs a newline:

```
base64 -D | od -c
Tmd1eWVuIFRyYW4gVmlldCBBCg==

0000000    N   g   u   y   e   n       T   r   a   n       V   i   e   t
0000020        A  \n                                                    
0000023
```

The ObjC example does not have the newline.  You probably did something like

```
[@"Nguyen Tran Viet A" base64Encode]
```

which produces:

```
base64 -D | od -c
Tmd1eWVuIFRyYW4gVmlldCBB

0000000    N   g   u   y   e   n       T   r   a   n       V   i   e   t
0000020        A                                                        
0000022
```

No ending newline.  So they are both correct -- you just encoded slightly different things.